# Show realtime updates of list of documents in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was working on an application where I needed real-time updates on a **list of documents** (using their *document-id* ) in firebase using kotlin flows. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your question, it's a little too broad to reasonably answer, here on Stackoverflow. However, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get updates in real-time on the list of documents, we can use queries.
like in this case, we can use `whereIn`

```
val listOfDocumentIds = getDocumentIdsList()
val listDocumentsFlow: Flow<QuerySnapshot> = collectionUserDetails.whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(),listOfDocumentIds).snapshots()
```

Answer (score 0):

**To view a list of documents in real time, use Firestore snapshot listener.**

*Check the link for more -* https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question that I want to get the flow of the whole collection. 
I just want to observe some documents as flow.